# Cannot send a struct over channel: mpsc::Sender cannot be shared between threads safely

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am struggling with sending a custom struct over channel.

I wrapped the value in an `Arc` and `Mutex` as described in the tutorial,
but it doesn't compile anyway.

```
extern crate num;

use num::bigint::BigInt;
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;
use readline::readline as ask;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

enum Command {
    Quit,
    Help,
    Factorial { n: BigInt },
    Error { msg: String },
}

fn main() {
    let (input_tx, input_rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let input_thread = thread::spawn(|| {
        input_tx.send(Arc::new(Mutex::new(Command::Quit)));
    });
}
```

```
error: the trait bound `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<Command>>>: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied [E0277]
    let input_thread = thread::spawn(|| {
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
note: `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<Command>>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `&std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<Command>>>`
note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:25:38: 65:6 input_tx:&std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<Command>>>]`
note: required by `std::thread::spawn`
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I am using Rust 1.10.0 (cfcb716cf 2016-07-03).

Comment: Note: you wrapped the value inside the channel, but the compiler here is complaining about the *sender* to the channel not being wrapped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust mpsc::Sender cannot be shared between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384274/rust-mpscsender-cannot-be-shared-between-threads)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure passed to `thread::spawn()` must be `move` (`FnOnce`). `Arc` and `Mutex` are not needed:

```
let input_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
    input_tx.send(Command::Quit);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this [MCVE](/help/mcve):

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;

enum Command {
    Quit,
    Error { msg: String },
}

fn main() {
    let (input_tx, input_rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let input_thread = thread::spawn(|| {
        input_tx.send(Command::Quit);
    });
}
```

And the error message:

> `std::sync::mpsc::Sender` cannot be **shared** between threads safely; required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for ` **&** std::sync::mpsc::Sender`

(emphasis mine)

By default, a closure captures *a reference* to any variables used within it. This is what you want most of the time, as giving up ownership is more restrictive for the creator of the closure. Using a reference allows the captured value to be shared between outside the closure and inside and doesn't require moving any bits around.

In this case, you **do** want to give ownership of `input_tx` to the closure. This is because ownership of the closure itself will be given to a new thread, so the closure and everything in it needs to be safe to be handed to another thread. A *reference* to a `Sender` may not be shared among threads.

A [`move` closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/closures.html#move-closures) requests that ownership of any captured variables be transferred to the closure. By doing this, there is no sharing and all the requirements are met. As [aSpex said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303808/155423):

```
let input_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
    input_tx.send(Command::Quit);
});
```

---

Occasionally you need to transfer ownership of some captured variables but want to share others. Since `move` closures are all-or-nothing, you need to be more explicit in this case. You can simply take a reference before the closure:

```
let a = 42;
let a_ref = &a;

let input_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
    println!("{}", a_ref);
});
```

This doesn't work because the reference to `a` is not `'static`, but shows the general idea.