# Rust mpsc::Sender cannot be shared between threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I thought the whole purpose of a channel was to share data between threads.  I have this code, [based on this example](http://rustbyexample.com/std_misc/channels.html):

```
let tx_thread = tx.clone();
let ctx = self;
thread::spawn(|| {
    ...
    let result = ctx.method()
    tx_thread.send((String::from(result), someOtherString)).unwrap();
})
```

Where `tx` is a `mpsc::Sender<(String, String)>`

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<(std::string::String, std::string::String)>: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied
   --> src/my_module/my_file.rs:137:9
    |
137 |         thread::spawn(|| {
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<(std::string::String, std::string::String)>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `&std::sync::mpsc::Sender<(std::string::String, std::string::String)>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/my_module/my_file.rs:137:23: 153:10 res:&&str, ctx:&&my_module::my_submodule::Reader, tx_thread:&std::sync::mpsc::Sender<(std::string::String, std::string::String)>]`
    = note: required by `std::thread::spawn`
```

I'm confused where I went wrong.  Unless I'm looking in the wrong place and my issue is actually my use of `let ctx = self;`?

Comment: For hindsights into `Send` and `Sync`, you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387421/what-are-examples-of-types-that-implement-only-one-of-send-and-sync

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Sender cannot be *shared* between threads, but it can be *sent*!

It implements the trait `Send` but not `Sync` (Sync: Safe to access shared reference to `Sender` across threads).

The design of channels intends that you `.clone()` the sender and pass it as a value to a thread (for each thread you have). You are missing the `move` keyword on the thread's closure, which instructs the closure to capture variables by taking ownership of them.

If you must share a single channel endpoint between several threads, it must be wrapped in a mutex. `Mutex<Sender<T>>` *is* `Sync + Send where T: Send`.

Interesting implementation note: The channel starts out for use as a stream where it has a single producer. The internal data structures are upgraded to a multi-producer implementation the first time a sender is cloned.

Comment: Regarding your implementation note: is this still the case today, and where might I find info on it? Around `sync/mpsc/chan.rs` I cannot find anything that hints at this.

Comment: Sender is now `Sync` (since 1.72.0)

Answer (score 6):

You may use [std::sync::mpsc::SyncSender](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.SyncSender.html) from the standard library. The diffrenece is that it implements the `Sync` trait but it will may block if there is no space in the internal buffer while sending a message.

For more information:

- [std::sync::mpsc::channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html)
- [std::sync::mpsc::sync_channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.sync_channel.html)