# Why do I get an error that "Sync is not satisfied" when moving self, which contains an Arc, into a new thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a struct which holds an `Arc<Receiver<f32>>` and I'm trying to add a method which takes ownership of `self`, and moves the ownership into a new thread and starts it. However, I'm getting the error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<f32>: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
19 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<f32>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<f32>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<f32>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Foo`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:19:23: 22:10 self:Foo]`
   = note: required by `std::thread::spawn`
```

If I change the struct to hold an `Arc<i32>` instead, or just a `Receiver<f32>`, it compiles, but not with a `Arc<Receiver<f32>>`. How does this work? The error doesn't make sense to me as I'm not trying to share it between threads (I'm moving it, not cloning it).

Here is the full code:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver, Sender};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

pub struct Foo {
    receiver: Arc<Receiver<f32>>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new() -> (Foo, Sender<f32>) {
        let (sender, receiver) = channel::<f32>();
        let sink = Foo {
            receiver: Arc::new(receiver),
        };
        (sink, sender)
    }

    pub fn run_thread(self) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("Thread spawned by 'run_thread'");
            self.run(); // <- This line gives the error
        })
    }

    fn run(mut self) {
        println!("Executing 'run'")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (example, sender) = Foo::new();
    let handle = example.run_thread();
    handle.join();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust mpsc::Sender cannot be shared between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384274/rust-mpscsender-cannot-be-shared-between-threads)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How does this work?

Let's check the requirements of [`thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) again:

```
pub fn spawn<F, T>(f: F) -> JoinHandle<T> 
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,   // <-- this line is important for us
    T: Send + 'static,
```

Since `Foo` contains an `Arc<Receiver<_>>`, let's check if and how [`Arc` implements `Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#impl-Send):

```
impl<T> Send for Arc<T> 
where
    T: Send + Sync + ?Sized,
```

So `Arc<T>` implements `Send` if `T` implements `Send` *and* `Sync`. And while [`Receiver` implements `Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#impl-Send), [it does *not* implement `Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#impl-Sync).

So why does `Arc` have such strong requirements for `T`? `T` also has to implement `Send` because `Arc` can act like a container; if you could just hide something that doesn't implement `Send` in an `Arc`, send it to another thread and unpack it there... bad things would happen. The interesting part is to see why `T` also has to implement `Sync`, which is apparently also the part you are struggling with:

> The error doesn't make sense to me as I'm not trying to share it between threads (I'm moving it, not cloning it).

The compiler can't know that the `Arc` in `Foo` is in fact not shared. Consider if you would add a `#[derive(Clone)]` to `Foo` later (which is possible without a problem):

```
fn main() {
    let (example, sender) = Foo::new();
    let clone = example.clone();
    let handle = example.run_thread();
    clone.run();
    // oopsie, now the same `Receiver` is used from two threads!

    handle.join();
}
```

In the example above there is only one `Receiver` which is shared between threads. And this is no good, since `Receiver` does not implement `Sync`!

To me this code raises the question: why the `Arc` in the first place? As you noticed, without the `Arc`, it works without a problem: you clearly state that `Foo` is the only owner of the `Receiver`. And if you are "not trying to share [the Receiver]" anyway, there is no point in having multiple owners.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot more sense now! The reason for wanting it in an Arc is because I want to use it from within a closure which is called from C-code later on (PortAudio), but I have a feeling I should probably think of a better way to do it.

Comment: @AndréT. If you have multiple consumers of the channel, you should probably use a library that has mpmc channels, like [`crossbeam-channel`](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam-channel). Then, your `Receiver` is `Sync`. Or you could ask on `/r/rust` or in the users forum what others would recommend in your situation :)