# How to share a struct containing a Sender and a Receiver field across threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust, channel

I have a struct which roughly looks as follows

```
struct Node {
    id: Arc<i32>,
    data: Arc<Mutex<i32>>, // Actually not i32, but that is not important for this question.
    rx: Receiver<()>,
    tx: Sender<()>
}
```

I use `Receiver` and `Sender` from `mpsc::channel`.

I want to share this across multiple threads. I have one "user" thread in which the user of `Node` executes some functions on `Node`. This will cause some UDP messages being sent to other computers and this thread will block on `rx.recv()`. In the background I have one *or more* threads that perform a blocking receive call on UDP sockets. When they receive a message they update the `data` field of the `Node` struct and when a background thread notices that sufficiently many messages have been received, it will send `()` using `tx.send()`, to let the user-thread continue its execution.

To share a `Node` instance to another thread, I do something like this:

```
let node: Arc<Node> = ...
let node_for_background_thread = Arc::clone(&node);
let background_thread_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    node_for_background_thread.start_receive_loop();
});
```

I need to access all fields of `Node` (e.g. `id` and `data`) in both the user thread and the background threads. That's why I want to share a single instance of `Node` across them. But neither `Receiver` nor `Sender` is `Sync`, so the above doesn't compile. I know I can clone `Sender` to put an owned one of them in each background thread.

One solution I see is to not include `rx` and `tx` in `Node`. But then I would lose encapsulation since then the creator of `Node` instances would have to create the channel and also spawn the background threads. I want to keep it all encapsulated in `Node` if possible.

The code snipper above is where I could manually clone the `Sender`. I don't need to clone the `Receiver` since I will only ever have one thread that will use it.

Comment: Are you using `std::mpsc`? `Sender` is `Clone`, you should give each thread their own clone of the sender. However the `sc` means Single Consumer, so you can't share the `Receiver` by design. The `crossbeam` crate provides MPMC channels similar to the ones in std.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I will update my questions to clarify a little.

Comment: You could wrap your `Receiver` into `Arc<Mutex<..>>` as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust mpsc::Sender cannot be shared between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384274/rust-mpscsender-cannot-be-shared-between-threads)

Answer (score 0):

As I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65354846/6070255

> You may use [std::sync::mpsc::SyncSender](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.SyncSender.html) from the standard library. The difference is that it implements the `Sync` trait but it will may block if there is no space in the internal buffer while sending a message.
>
> For more information:
>
> - [std::sync::mpsc::channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html)
> - [std::sync::mpsc::sync_channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.sync_channel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since all the other fields are wrapped in `Arc` already it's easy, you can just wrap the `Receiver` into an `Arc<Mutex<~>>`, too (though of course using a `Receiver` that's meant to be shared like the one from `crossbeam` would be even better). The `Sender` is already designed to be cloned. Then instead of passing around references, you just `clone` the `Node`s directly, no need to wrap in `Arc` anymore:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Node {
    id: Arc<i32>,
    data: Arc<Mutex<i32>>, // Actually not i32, but that is not important for this question.
    rx: Arc<Mutex<Receiver<()>>>,
    tx: Sender<()>
}
```

and to share:

```rust
let node: Node = ...
let node_for_background_thread = node.clone();
let background_thread_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    node_for_background_thread.start_receive_loop();
});
```