# Cannot Send A Struct Across Threads which has mpsc::Sender as field

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a struct which has `Sender` type as its field.

```rust
pub struct GenericConnectionPool<E>
where
    E: ConnectionConnector,
{
    _sender: Sender<()>,
    _reciever: Arc<Mutex<Receiver<()>>>,
    _num_of_live_connections: AtomicU8,
    _max_connections: u8,
    _min_connections: u8,
    _connections: Arc<Mutex<Vec<<E as ConnectionConnector>::Conn>>>,
    _connector: E,
}
```

I am using the struct across multiple threads, that is why, while using it inside Arc and clone it.

```rust
let pool = Arc::new(GenericConnectionPool::new(2, 1, cc));
println!("here");
{
    for _ in 0..3 {
        let pool = Arc::clone(&pool);
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            pool.get_connection();
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
        });
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error that my struct cannot be sent across threads.

```
`std::sync::mpsc::Sender<()>` cannot be shared between threads safely
within `GenericConnectionPool<tests::connector_works::DummyConnectionConnector>`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<()>`
required because it appears within the type `GenericConnectionPool<tests::connector_works::DummyConnectionConnector>`
required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Arc<GenericConnectionPool<tests::connector_works::DummyConnectionConnector>>`
required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:169:36: 172:18 pool:std::sync::Arc<GenericConnectionPool<tests::connector_works::DummyConnectionConnector>>]`
```

What I understood is that the `Sender` type cannot be sent safely across threads, but since its `cloneable`, you can clone it and then send it across the thread. But in my situation, sender is inside my Struct. I can't figure out a way to fix this.

I am thinking I might have to change my design.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust mpsc::Sender cannot be shared between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384274/rust-mpscsender-cannot-be-shared-between-threads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Crossbeam. Its `crossbeam::Sender` seems to be transferable between threads. Presumably, you'd need to use its `crossbeam::Receiver` too.

Alternatively, you could refactor your GenericConnectionPool to be like this:

```
pub struct ExtraData {}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct GenericConnectionPool {
    _sender: Sender<()>,
    _extra_data: Arc<ExtraData>,
}
```

then you can clone the GenericConnectionPool directly rather than an Arc containing it and get the correct behaviour:

```
let pool = GenericConnectionPool{_sender:s, _extra_data:Arc::new(ExtraData{}) };

for _ in 0..3 {
   let pool = pool.clone();
   std::thread::spawn(move || {
       pool.get_connection();
       thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    });
}
```

You can see a compiling version [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e00fc85070ecc97e2739b7b378f41834):

Comment: This is exactly what i decided to go with. https://github.com/kumarmo2/connection-pool/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L53 .

But I will also look at the crossbeam library, you have mentioned. Thanks a lot.