# Rust lifetime issue brought on by Mutex of data

Tags: rust

I've narrowed this as much as I can. I have a vector of references to `Senders` and want to process them after `receive()` has completed running. However I'm running into a lifetime management issue. The inner struct is `Mutex` protected and contains the `Senders` that I'm trying to reference. I use the Mutex to gain mutability of the data, I'm open to alternatives. Any suggestions on how to work around this? I'd prefer not to change the signature of receive().

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::mpsc;

#[derive(Default)]
struct SaveForLater<'a> {
    queue: Vec<(&'a mpsc::Sender<usize>, usize)>,
}
impl<'a> SaveForLater<'a> {
    fn send(&mut self, channel: &'a mpsc::Sender<usize>, value: usize) {
        self.queue.push((channel, value));
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Forwarder {
    data: Mutex<ForwarderData>,
}
#[derive(Default)]
struct ForwarderData {
    senders: Vec<mpsc::Sender<usize>>,
}

impl Forwarder {
    fn with_capacity(capacity: usize) -> Self {
        let mut senders = Vec::new();
        for _ in 0..capacity {
            let (s,r) = mpsc::channel();
            senders.push(s);
        }
        let data = ForwarderData { senders };
        let data = Mutex::new(data);
        Self { data }
    }

    fn receive<'a>(&'a self, value: usize, sender: &mut SaveForLater<'a>) {
        match value {
            0 => { self.data.lock().unwrap().senders.drain(..); },
            _ => {
                let data = self.data.lock().unwrap();
                sender.send(&data.senders[0], value); },
/*
error[E0597]: `data` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:40:30
   |
35 |     fn receive<'a>(&'a self, value: usize, sender: &mut SaveForLater<'a>) {
   |                -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
40 |                 sender.send(&data.senders[0], value); },
   |                 -------------^^^^-------------------  - `data` dropped here while still borrowed
   |                 |            |
   |                 |            borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 argument requires that `data` is borrowed for `'a`
*/
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let fwd = Forwarder::with_capacity(3);
    {
        let mut sender = SaveForLater::default();
        let value: usize = 42;
        fwd.receive(value, &mut sender);
        for (s,v) in sender.queue {
            s.send(v);
        }   
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_main() {
        main();
    }
}
```

see error in [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b3355f447a3579bf47318c718b4c3fa)

Answer (score 1):

`Mutex` is a distraction here; the real problem is trying to store references in structs. Let's look at the documentation of [`mpsc::Sender`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html) to see how it's supposed to be used:

> The sending-half of Rust's asynchronous [`channel`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) type. This half **can only be owned by one thread, but it can be cloned** to send to other threads.

`Sender` does not even implement `Sync`, so even if you make the borrow checker happy [you won't be able to share a single one between multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40384274/3650362). It's meant to be **cloned** instead:

```
struct SaveForLater {
    queue: Vec<(mpsc::Sender<usize>, usize)>,
}
```

```
    fn receive(&self, value: usize, sender: &mut SaveForLater) {
        // ...
                sender.send(data.senders[0].clone(), value);
                //                         ^^^^^^^^
```

[Here's a full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b84099bfce3c7b5c9d6e3180d0149c7b). No lifetime parameters are necessary.

In general you should avoid putting references in structs because it can only be done safely if you are very diligent about proving the lifetime relationships at compile time. In most cases you should simply clone the data, or if that's the wrong semantic, use `Arc` or `Rc`. `mpsc::Sender` uses `Arc` internally to be cheap to clone.

Comment: I used mpsc::Sender as a simplification. The actual code is using smol::channel::Sender, I was hoping to avoid the overhead of clone(), either Arc or Sender.

Comment: The borrow checker fundamentally does *static lifetime analysis*, and you have data with lifetimes that *can't be analyzed statically* because they depend on runtime behavior. If you're not going to store all the `Sender`s in an arena, or a pre-filled `Vec` or something (meaning they all get destroyed at once), you **need** runtime checking of some kind (or you can just leak memory). It's not overhead if you need it.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's it -- it does static lifetime analysis, and of course I look at it and say its fine, but only because I'm looking at the code structure and usage, essentially doing runtime analysis. Thanks for setting me head straight.

Comment: Exactly! Yes, I think the Rust compiler sometimes *seems* magical enough that we can be disappointed when it refuses to perform *literal magic* when asked. Anyway, that's happened to me on multiple occasions.

Comment: So, that's fixed... Now I just have to figure out how to resurrect a concrete type from an Any that I stored in a HashMap :(