# Sharing between threads with mpsc::Sender and mpsc::Receiver

Tags: multithreading, rust, channel

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384274/rust-mpscsender-cannot-be-shared-between-threads) post but couldn't figure out where I was going wrong with my code. I have a vector of structs that each contain an `mpsc::Sender` and `mpsc::Receiver` and I'm trying to move each of these structs into a thread and keep getting this compile error (and a symmetrical one for the Sender). Since the Sender and Receiver are part of a struct, I wasn't sure how to clone them.

```
for obj in objs.iter() {
  let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<abc::xyz>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    obj.do_something();
    ...
  });
  ...
}
```

Comment: Here is a recommendation that will save you a lot of time: switch to [crossbeam-channel](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam-channel), whose sender and receiver are both `Send` and `Sync`. (They're also more efficient and have a better-thought-out API.)

Answer (score 3):

> for obj in objs.iter() {

This means `obj` is an `&T`. The `move` closure means the reference gets moved into the closure but… that's it. It's a reference. Meaning the type being referenced must be `Sync` (and also you'll have lifetime issues because stdlib threads are not *scoped*, so the compiler will eventually tell you that the references don't live long enough).

If `objs` is a vector, removing the `.iter()` will fix *that* issue though it may trigger new ones: it'll perform an "owned" iteration, so you will be moving the obj itself into the loop.

If `objs` is *not* a vector, then make it a vector somehow because a slice can't hand out owned objects. Or clone everything but I rather doubt that's what you want. Your final option is to put every obj inside an `Arc`, and probably a `Mutex/RwLock` if you want to mutate them.